# AWS Glue Bookmark: run job vs trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I was wondering whether for a specific Job with bookmarking enabled how does it work the logic if I alternate **Run Job** with **Trigger Runs**.

**EXAMPLE**

I run my job manually with the *Run Job* button and processes the input files in a specific folder. In this input folder new files are created. After half an hour the job is fired by a scheduled trigger.

Would the scheduled trigger be aware of the processed files by the "manual" run job or would be a different bookmarking process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkpoints for Job Bookmark are saved vis a vis the transformation_ctx and the updated to checkpoints are commited when the `job.commit()` command is run from the script.

Since running the job via trigger or manually, causes the invocatin of same API action (StartJobRun) and these job runs are virtually running the same code, each new job run will know about the bookmark update from the previous run.